# Make Header View (not Section Header) of ListView Stick on Top

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with a HeaderView.

I want one of the views in the `HeaderView` to stick on top.

I've seen a lot of examples for sticky Section Headers.

I also looked at [StickyScrollViewItems](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems) but since I'm using a `ListView`, I cannot use a `ScrollView`.

Is there a library available for this or should I just override the `OnScrollListener` of the `ListView`?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying and state what the current result is? If you are using `addHeaderView(v)` and adding them in the correct order then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @codeMagic I just looked at the libraries I mentioned. I used addHeaderView but I cannot figure out how to make it stick. The examples are for Section Headers not HeaderView for ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any library that lets you do this but what I do for a header is to use a `RelativeLayout` for my xml that will have the `ListView`. Then create your header view however you want and give it the property

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

then give your `ListView`

```
android:layout_below="@id/idOfHeaderView
```

This is the easiest way I know of to dock a header view at the top. It has worked for me every time. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my post wasn't clear. I have 3 views lined vertically in my HeaderView. I only want the 3rd view to stick.

Comment: I see. That seems a bit strange but maybe I don't understand what you are doing exactly. You can't have the 3rd view be the first and stick at the top and have the two below that move with the `ListView`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be the first view. So my workaround is to put that 3rd view in a Section Header that is only displayed on the 1st item on the ListView.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I think the wording of this is a little confusing. Basically make your list view xml be a relative layout that contains a view with your desired header and then your list view below that with layoutbelow set.

Comment: @AdamJohns I'm not sure which part is confusing but if you have a way to make it sound more clear, feel free to edit.

Comment: @codeMagic I think the part that confused me (and maybe I'm just misunderstanding) is that you say "then give your ListView android:layout_below="@id/idOfListView". I think what you meant is android:layout_below="@id/idOfHeaderView"? Otherwise you are laying out the ListView below itself?

Comment: @AdamJohns Ah, nice catch and thanks! Yes, that would actually result in a circular dependency error. I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

I have just written a load of code that does this that I cant share for contractoral reasons. Basically follow the approach outlined [here](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/07/18/android-tips-and-tricks-synchronized-scrolling.html) and apply to a listview rather than a scroll view.

Main points are

1. Create a wrapper view that contains your floating/sticky header and your listview as siblings
2. Use a proxy method when adding headers with an isSticky boolean - if is sticky then add a fake blank header to the listview of the same size and your intended header view to the floating header wrapper (use a relative layout here)
3. Set a scroll listener of the listview that tracks the top px position of the dummy header view in the list and setting this as a top margin of the floating header that sits inside a relative layout
4. Handle all the annoying edge cases / OEM overscroll crap to get it to work in all situtions (like [this](https://gist.github.com/DHuckaby/3919939) for samsung)

Remember to set the initial position of the floating/pinned header after the listview has been layed out.

I feel its a little bit involved and takes some tweaking to get right - this is a time where i envy iOS and any iOS devs will think your slacking as it takes a while to implement :D

All the Open libs out there at time of writing are using scroll views or list view headers. This issue with these approaches are that list views recycle views (so unlike scroll views you cant just keep a ref to the dummy view) and also the current libs seem duplicate the sticky views using adapter `getView` methods and so on - which is no good for dynamic list view header views as they are not recycled and can only have one parent, so reparenting would be annoying (and in my case has a lot of functionality so I defo dont want to create two views of the same type and shoehorn the current libs to fit my solutions)

Comment: I really wish you could share your code but the explanation works for me. Seems I have my work cut out for me.

Comment: I feel for you - just persuade the client not to do it ;)

Comment: Let's just say this is an extremely well paying client. :)